# I have successfully created a scalar function, but get an error The multi-part identifier "dbo.unpivottest3" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

My function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[unpivottest3]() 
RETURNS int
AS BEGIN
   DECLARE @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
           @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

   --select particular columns  
   SELECT @colsUnpivot = STUFF((SELECT ',' + quotename(C.column_name)
                                FROM information_schema.columns AS C
                                WHERE C.table_name = 'tblKRI Dump' 
                                  AND C.column_name LIKE '%-20%'
                                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')

   SET @query = 'insert into BI_DWH.tblKRI_Dump1 select 
u.SECTOR_NAME,
u.LOB_NAME,
u.INDICATOR_GROUP_NAME,
u.USER_DEFINED_INDICATOR_ID,
u.INDICATOR_NAME,
u.INDICATOR_DESCRIPTION,
u.CLASSIFICATION,
u.SCORE_GREEN_THRESHOLD,
u.SCORE_RED_THRESHOLD,
u.INDICATOR_PRIORITY,
u.INDICATOR_HOW_TO_ACQUIRE,
u.CAUSE,
u.IMPACT,
u.ACTION_PLAN,
u.RESOLUTION_EXPECTED,
u.RESOLUTION_TARGET_DATE,
u.NO_RESOLUTION_REASON,
u.Memo_Last_Updated,
u.RISK_CATEGORY,
u."RISK_SUB-CATEGORY",
u.Updated_By,
u.Updated_On,
u.SCORE_1_Red_2_Amb_3_Grn,
 u.Monthkey, u.value
from [BI_DWH].[tblKRI Dump] 
unpivot
(
  value
  for monthkey in ('+ @colsunpivot +')
) u
'
    EXEC sp_executesql @query

    RETURN 0
END
```

Comment: Please add some context, and proper formatting. Without these two things it's very difficult to grasp what you're doing and why it doesn't work.

Comment: Cant perform table actions in a function....only aquisition or value effect

Comment: You can't have dynamic sql in a function. https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/29/sql-server-user-defined-functions-udf-limitations/

Comment: Current data Format         
INDICATOR_PRIORITY INDICATOR_HOW_TO_ACQUIRE Jun-16 Jul-16 Aug-16 Sep-16 Oct-16 Nov-16 Dec-16 Jan-17
Moderate  6 10 7 -14 4 11 6 -2
Moderate  6 1 4 -6 7 15 8 1
Moderate  0.01 0.003 0 0 0.01 0 0.005 0.0025
Expected Format   Newly Added Column      
Updated_By Updated_On SCORE_1_Red_2_Amb_3_Grn Monthkey Value     
XBBJTDW 18:04.4 3 Feb-17 10     
XBBJTDW 18:04.4 3 Mar-17 21     
XBBJTDW 18:04.4 3 Apr-17 -9     
XBBJTDW 18:04.4 3 May-17 6     
XBBJTDW 18:04.4 3 Jun-16 0.01     
     
headers are dynamic so please help to achieve this

Comment: Data is in pivot format and i need to unpivot it. Challange is data headers are dynamic (June-206,Jul 2016,Aug-2016,..etc which will be changing) . If i use above query, its working fine but i need to use this SQL in SSIS where its not working(SSIS does not support "Declare"..). Need help to achieve this in single SQL which then can be used in SSIS